# Http client cURL alternative

Tags: php, curl

I was wondering, is there a PHP HTTP client project similar to cURL, that supports cookies? I've run into some issues, so I'm looking for an alternative.

Comment: curl perfectly supports cookies.

Comment: Guzzle! Guzzle is becoming the de facto do-all HTTP client for PHP. https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle . But, mostly it just wraps cURL functionality (which _does_ support cookies!)

Comment: ^^ But Guzzle is far from lean. Post the actual issues you're having with curl & cookies, and we can help sort them out. That avoids adding a big dependency.

Comment: I'm not sure what's the actual problem, or that cURL is the real cause. I am simply using cURL to send GET request,  but the response is different then using a normal browser. Not drastically, but piece of html code is simply not returned.

Comment: @Zed I doubt using a different library will fix that. Chances are it's either a) loaded via AJAX or b) being shown only to certain user agents.

Comment: @ceejayoz, I eliminated both things, disabled JS in browser and got the same response back. Tried setting User agent to the same value that my browser is using, again, nothing is changed. Maybe I missed something, I don't know, but I'll be sure when I try Guzzle.

Comment: Just to let you know guys, Guzzle solved my problem!